# Using query to extract date ranges

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a column with dates:

```
df.my_dates

0    2014-06-08
1    2014-03-01
...
148   2014-06-25
149   2014-06-02
Name: my_dates, Length: 150, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And the following dates:

```
> d1 
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 5, 0, 0)

> d2
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0)
```

I would like to extract all entries between those two dates. I have tried:

```
# The statement below translates into "'2014-06-05' > my_dates > '2014-06-09'"
my_query = "'{}' > my_dates > '{}'".format(d1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), 
                                           d2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
df.reset_index().query(my_query)
```

with no luck. I get an empty dataframe, even though I can see data between those two dates.

How can I retrieve data between those two dates? (note that the dates themshelves may not occur in the dataframe)). Can I use query for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use normal filtering by multiple criteria: the `&` operator and parentheses around each criteria. Pandas is able to compare dates out of the box.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range(start='2014-06-02', freq='2D',
                                         periods=50),
                   "value": 1})

d1 = datetime(2014, 6, 5, 0, 0)
d2 = datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0)

df = df[(df['date'] > d1) & (df['date'] < d2)]

print df
```

This prints:

```
        date  value
2 2014-06-06      1
3 2014-06-08      1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `query` method, there are two things needs to be changed:

```
In [32]:

from datetime import datetime
d1 = datetime(2014, 6, 5, 0, 0)
d2 = datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0)
d1=pd.to_datetime(d1) #or pd.DatetimeIndex(d1)
d2=pd.to_datetime(d2) 
print df
           val     
0   2014-06-08
1   2014-03-01
148 2014-06-25
149 2014-06-02
In [33]:

print df.query('(@d1 < val)&(val<@d2)')
         val    
0 2014-06-08
```

You see, 1st, `d1` and `d2` have to be converted to `timestamps`. 2nd, `d1` and `d2` are external variables, so `@` is need in front of them in the query.